# why does this erroneous python format produce this result and not an exception?

Tags: python-2.7, format

I've tracked down a bug to incorrect placement of `:` in a format.

But I don't yet understand the behavior. Why does the 2nd line generate two pi's (wrong 2nd value) but proper formatting, rather than throw an exception?

```
import math
data  = math.pi, math.e

print 'pi={:0.2f}, e={:0.4f}'.format(*data)
print 'pi={0:.2f}, e={0:.4f} wrong!'.format(*data)   # wrong!
```

gives

```
pi=3.14, e=2.7183
pi=3.14, e=3.1416 wrong!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number before the colon is the index of the arguments, so in your second `print` both `{0:.2f}` and `{0:.4f}` are printing the same argument of index 0, which is `math.pi`.

Excerpt from [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

> ```
> replacement_field ::=  "{" [field_name] ["!" conversion] [":" format_spec] "}"
> field_name        ::=  arg_name ("." attribute_name | "[" element_index "]")*
> ```

Note the `field_name` before `:`, which can be an element index.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I do a lot of numerical work but have never bothered to format text until recently, then there was *old style* versus *new style*... This concise explanation is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Try another? [Natural way to inspect a python format to determine the number of values it's expecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51609953/3904031)