# Evaluate python format string for number of values expected

Tags: python-2.7, format

I have a method that receives a format string and a set of values provided by a user, and uses these to write an output to a screen.

```
def makestring(fmt, vals):
    s = fmt.format(*vals)
    return s

fmt_expecting_three = 'a={:0.2f}, b={:0.4f}, c={:0.1f}'

threevalues = [(x+1)/7. for x in range(3)]

makestring(fmt_expecting_three, threevalues)
```

produces

```
'a=0.14, b=0.2857, c=0.4'
```

I would like to perform a test to discover the number of values matches what the format is "expecting".

I show an ugly test below, that can give incorrect results if you don't set `maxcheck` high enough. Is there a more natural, less ugly way to find out how many values are expected?

```
def checkit(fmt, maxcheck=None):
    if maxcheck == None:
        maxcheck = 10
    for i in range(maxcheck-1, 0, -1):
        try:
            fmt.format(*range(i))
        except:
            return i+1

fmt_expecting_three = 'a={:0.2f}, b={:0.4f}, c={:0.1f}'

checkit(fmt_expecting_three)
```

returns

```
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this with [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter). This ensures that the string is actually a valid format string, whilst giving you all the information about the format.
Take:

```
>>> import string
>>> f = string.Formatter()
>>> l = list(f.parse('Hello, {noun!s: ^4} world{}!'))
>>> l
[('Hello, ', 'noun', ' ^4', 's'), (' world', '', '', None), ('!', None, None, None)]
```

From this you can count the amount by checking if the second item is None or not.

```
>>> sum(1 for _, field_name, _, _ in l if field_name is not None)
2
```

And so you can use:

```
def count_formats(format_string):
    f = string.Formatter()
    formats = f.parse(format_string)
    return sum(1 for _, field_name, _, _ in formats if field_name is not None)
```

---

This however doesn't work with nested formats. And so we need to check what can be nested:

```
>>> list(f.parse('{}'))
[('', '', '', None)]
>>> list(f.parse('{:{}}'))
[('', '', '{}', None)]
>>> list(f.parse('{{}:{}}'))
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
>>> list(f.parse('{!{}:{}}'))
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

And so we only need to check format spec to see if there are any nested formats. And so you can change `count_formats` to be nested if you'd like:

```
def count_formats(format_string):
    def nested(s):
        for hit in f.parse(s):
            yield hit
            if hit[2]:
                for nested_hit in nested(hit[2]):
                    yield nested_hit
    f = string.Formatter()
    formats = nested(format_string)
    return sum(1 for _, field_name, _, _ in formats if field_name is not None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though learning regex is painful, it pays off!

Modified from http://www.rexegg.com/regex-cookbook.html

```
things = ['pi={:0.2f}, e={:0.4f}', 'pi={:0.2f}, e={q', '{{}',
          '{}wow', 'wow', '{}']      # includes some pathologicals

import re

for thing in things:
    print len(re.findall('{([^{)]*)}', thing)), thing
```

returns

```
2 pi={:0.2f}, e={:0.4f}
1 pi={:0.2f}, e={q
1 {{}
1 {}wow
0 wow
1 {}
```

yay!

Comment: @Peilonrayz this is what I've got so far, ideally someone better at this than I will post a better answer. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51608190/why-does-this-erroneous-python-format-produce-this-result-and-not-an-exception?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment90181605_51608302) I'm new to non-numerical uses of  Python. Any improvements, or a new answer would be greatly appreciated! I'll only be using this for simple formats and numberical values but a more general answer would be better.

Comment: *[Much better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51648815/3904031)* than mine!

Answer (score -1):

For something like this, I tend to look at the way the Python interpreter solves the problem, rather than reinventing the wheel.

I found a [C function in python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Python/modsupport.c#L43) called `countformat()`. (This also [looks about the same in Python 2.7](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/modsupport.c#L110).)

Next step would be to see if this function is exposed, or is strictly C. I did a [code search](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?q=countformat&unscoped_q=countformat). It looks like the answer is no, so I'd probably just copy whatever they did but do it in Python instead. It might be more efficient to write a regular expression, but that C function at least gives you an idea of how to define your regex.

The general algorithm is as follows:

- Set level to 0 and count to 0.
- Iterate through the format string. For each character:
- If you encounter an opening format marker `(`, `[`, `{`:

  - If level is 0, increment count.
  - Increment level.
- Else if you encounter a closing format marker `)`, `]`, `}`:

  - If level is 0, decrement count.
  - Decrement level.
- Else if you find some other marker `#`, `&`, `:`, , `\t`:

  - Do nothing.
- Else (some other character):

  - If level is 0, increment count.
- Return count.

Comment: Since I am [allergic to](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28223/12102) curly braces, my C is not so good. It's been several *decades* since I've looked at it, so I don't have a clue how that C works. Can you answer in Python? Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh I won't write your Python code for you, but I did translate the C into pseudocode for you.

Comment: English is also a language without curly braces. However that's totally wrong as it tends to always return zero no matter how many values are expected. Trivial example: `{}` another [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51608190/3904031): `pi={:0.2f}, e={:0.4f}`. You don't have to "write my Python code for me" but don't forget to at least test your answer's validity before posting it.

Comment: For Python's "new style" formatting, I wonder if simply counting the number of `{` might be at least the beginnings of an answer, perhaps with confirmation of an equal number of `}`? Or perhaps there's just a small error in your posted pseudocode?